# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=+123456789 pkg=com.android.phone }

Tags: android

The following code works fine when I click a button in an activity but gets an "No Activity found to handle Intent" error when a button in an fragment is clicked.

```
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("+123456789"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you should say that the data you are adding is tel number like this :
`callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+123456789"));`

here is a complete solution:

first of all, add the following permission to your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

then use following code for making call :

```
String phone = "+34666777888";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));
startActivity(intent);
```

update :

you don't need `CALL_PHONE` permission for `ACTION_DIAL`.

Comment: `CALL_PHONE` permission is not needed for `ACTION_DIAL`, just for `ACTION_CALL`. See [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#DialPhone).

Comment: @DavidMiguel I updated the answer. thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to your mainfest file for API's higher than 22

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

then use this code

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+123456789"));
        startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+123456789"));
        IntentChooser chooser= Intent.createChooser(callIntent,"title")
        startActivity(chooser);
```

Hope it helps.Make sure you have added appropriate permissions in manifest file.

Answer (score -4):

add this code will work properly

```
//string phone="034028477736"
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.Action-dial,Uri.fromparts("tell",phone,null));
startactivity(intent);//
```

Comment: This is a coding part taken from accepted answer. Please do not just copy others answers.